# Vim and Vundle error

Tags: vim, plugins

```
Errors discovered when processing function vundle # scripts # complete .. <SNR> 47_load_scripts:
line 7:
E15: Invalid expression:
E15: Invalid expression:
Errors discovered when processing function vundle # scripts # complete:
line 6:
E714: List required
```

This is the error that I get when I do `:PluginInstall`

It seems like it won't search for plugins, even though I can do `:PluginInstall` "plugin" and it will install.

Comment: Can you format your question, and ask an actual question. Also show your vimrc (or at least the part that is causing the error)

Comment: @FDinoff done, sorry about that

Comment: What is in your vimrc?

Comment: @FDinoff i'm very sorry.

Comment: @FDinoff I have been busy but I really want VIM fixed... here's my vimrc

Comment: @FDinoff a.pomf.se/shifxo.vimrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error points to this function of Vundle:

```
func! s:load_scripts(bang)
    let f = expand(g:vundle#bundle_dir.'/.vundle/script-names.vim-scripts.org.json', 1)
    if a:bang || !filereadable(f)
        if 0 != s:fetch_scripts(f)
            return []
        end
    endif
    return eval(readfile(f, 'b')[0])
endf
```

The error is caused by attempting to `eval()` an empty string. It looks like your `script-names.vim-scripts.org.json` file exists, but is empty.

I don't know Vundle; maybe deleting that file will cause the plugin to recreate it; worth a try. Else, please [open an issue](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/issues) at the project's tracker to alert the author and ask for assistance.

Comment: i love you :33333